# java - How do I prevent cross-site forgery request

Tags: java

So, I've been advised that the application I've begun working on has preventive measures in place for Cross-Site Forgery Request (CSFR) when it comes to post request, but NOT for get request.

I've also been advised that I can obtain the source of the origin and the target of the origin, compare the host of each, and depending if they match or not do something. As of now, I currently have the below after doing some research, but I'm not there yet and could use some additional help. I'm very new to the profession, so I'm not even sure if I am on the right track.

```
    String refererHost = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("referer");

    String targetHost = request.getServerName();

    try {       
        refererHost = new URI(refererHost).getHost();

        if(!refererHost.equals(targetHost))
        {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect( ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath()+ADMIN_LOGOFF_URL);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURIException | NullPointerException e) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(ADMIN_LOGOFF_URL).forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: GET requests should not affect state according the HTTP spec.  The best way to protect against CSRF for get requests is to adhere to that.  As to your code, you need to describe what's not working the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) has the recommendations.  Your posted code (assuming that's a filter) is one of the recommendations so you're on the right track.  Using tokens is also recommended - hopefully you can re-use what was already done for POSTs without too much re-factoring.

Also check if your framework (if any) provides support for CSRF so you don't have to write your own code.

Comment: Thank you Andrew and yes it is a filter. Tokens are used with the post request. As of now, I believe I have the source/target host comparing to one another correctly and if they don't it ends the users session/directs them to the log off screen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a  the naming issue: its name is CSRF.
Here I quote a reference site :

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces an end user
>   to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they're
>   currently authenticated. CSRF attacks specifically target
>   state-changing requests, not theft of data, since the attacker has no
>   way to see the response to the forged request.

State-changing requests are those which can change the state of the target site. If the application is well written a GET method is read only while to change its state a POST, a DELETE or an UPDATE should be invoked (so it's right that you have to protect the POST method but not only that).

Let's make an example to clarify. Let's suppose that you are logged-in to your bank account. If you are under attack, an application on your PC may invoke a POST to execute a wire transfer in the same way you would click on a button in the legitimate application.

What is a reasonable way to protect yourself by this attack?
I know two of them.

The first one is the creation of a random token when the page preceding the dangerous one is invoked (think of it as the page you got by the GET method to show the screen asking for the addressee). This random token has to be saved in the user's session and also present in the page as an hidden field. When the POST method is executed on the server side the random token coming from the hidden field must be compared to the one stored in the user's session. If they don't match the transaction must be rejected.

The second one consists of asking for confirmation, maybe by means of a captcha to the user.

For much more detailed information I'd advise you to start from this site:
[https://owasp.org/](https://www.owasp.org)
that is a very good starting point for every developer because security is a quality every application is expected to have.